# Shortcut Primary Output Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer

I've written a program that uses the .Net framework, the Qt framework, and the Qwt framework.

I read that to make a shortcut on the desktop, you right-click on the Primary Output thing in the main window pane, and you select Create-Shortcut.  This doesn't appear to be an option for me.  If I right-click on the white bit of the pane, I can create a shortcut, however, I can't really seem to link that shortcut to the output.

[image: No shortcut]

[image: Shortcut]

[image: Right click on white bit]

[image: Primary Output not selectable]

The last image shows that in my application folder, the primary output is not there.  If I go to add it, it adds it to far left pane (solution explorer) and I end up with two there, but it still doesn't show up as an option for the shortcut.

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue, just ran across this blog post which worked for me:
http://geekanddo.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/visual-studio-setup-projects-wont-make-a-shortcut-to-the-primary-output/

In my case it was an extra slash in the output filename, as the author mentions.